# time out for access flask app on azure VM

Tags: azure, docker, flask, virtual-machine

I have a flask app running in a docker container on an Azure vm.

App is running at port 5000 and I'm exposing that port to docker

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
57cdce7b5b2b        auto_ml2:latest     "/bin/sh -c 'python3…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   serene_mcnulty
mlcontainers2@automl:/$
```

I'm trying to make the following API call:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://XX.XX.X.XX:5000/api/AutoML"
resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
```

But after a while, I just get a time out error:

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

I thought the port must be closed, so I added a rule for it and opened ports 80 and 5000-6000 and reboot the VM

[image]

But I get the same error after this.

**EDIT**

I tested it from the VM, there it works fine:

[image]

But from a remote request I keep getting the same error:

[image]

Comment: Can you access the API server inside the VM?

Comment: @CharlesXu Yes, inside the VM it is working. I tested it and update the question

Comment: @CharlesXu got it to work, had to open all the TCP ports...

Comment: Well, you can add the answer to describe the solution for this issue to help other communities. Or I would help you add it and you can accept it?

Comment: Sure, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, first, you need to make sure that you can access the container from the image inside the VM. Then you need to add the rule to allow all the TCP ports necessary in the NSG which associated with the VM. Finally, you can access the API server outside the VM via the VM public IP with the right port which allowed in the NSG rule.