# Can't access Flask App in Azure Compute Instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, flask, virtual-machine

First, I tested and confirmed that my Flask Python script works fine on my local machine. But I'm having problems while using it in the Azure compute instance inside the Machine learning Studio. Below is what I experienced:

My command:

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

It returned as beblow:

```
 * Serving Flask app "server"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://10.0.0.4:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

10.0.0.4 is the private IP of this Azure compute instance, and I couldn't access it using my local computer and Internet. The error came back as Connection Timed Out.

How could I access it using my local computer and Internet?

I tried http://(its public IP address) :5000/
But the same error was returned.

Other Notes: Vnet is enabled for this compute instance, as well as Port 5000 under Network Security Group.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [time out for access flask app on azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001283/time-out-for-access-flask-app-on-azure-vm)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was not running a container inside my VM, the FLASK app is running on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Azure compute instance (in the machine learning studio) is not accessible by the external IPs even the one with an assigned public IP address. Even SSH to these instances needs to be preconfigured, rather than changing the network inbound rules.

But the actual virtual machine will allow this. If you have the similiar problem, I would recommend try Azure virtual machines instead.